# How to break a listing?

Tags: code

For my listings of LaTeX I use the low key approach exemplified in the code below. The problem is, the input and output together must fit inside a page or else it messes up the layout and is cut short.

The idea is to split the listings that are too big into small ones. Splitting the `In:` (verbatim) part is not a problem. How would I do so for the `Out:` part? In this example, is there a way to grab the low level TeX code generated by `\lipsum[1-8]`?

PS I looked at the [Listings](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package, which does support splitting, but apparently is only for showcasing the input.

```
\documentclass[full]{l3doc}
\usepackage{mwe} % TEST
\usepackage{float} % DOC
\usepackage{cleveref} % DOC

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Listing}{h}{lop}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{Listing}
  \textbf{In:}

  \verb|\lipsum[1-8]|

  \textbf{Out:}

  \lipsum[1-8]

\end{Listing}

\end{document}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Look at tcolorbox package. It is certain that you will find there what are you looking for (eventhough I dont know what exact solution you want). I am using it to print listings + theyre output in breakable manner; non-breakable is default behaviour.

Comment: @TomášKruliš thanks for the tip. `tcblisting` + `breakable` are part of the answer. Now just need to figure out how to integrate `auto counter`...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

```
\documentclass[full]{l3doc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}

\begin{document}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]
{listing}[2][]{
  noparskip,
  breakable,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title=Listing~\thetcbcounter,
%  listing only,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
}

%\tcbsubtitle[before skip=\baselineskip]{My subtitle}

\begin{listing}{}
  \lipsum[1-8]
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, instead of `auto counter`, you could define new counter and use it with option `use counter`; if you want to have your listings numbered (I am using it for listings in multiple languages, easily each language has its own counter ;) ). `tcolorbox` is extremely versatile ;)